# this.$refs.myProperty.refresh is not a function

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a attached a reference value 'callingTable' on a vue-data-table (from vuetify) as below:

```
<v-data-table
 :headers="callingTableHeaders"
 :items="getCallingDetails"
 class="elevation-1"
 ref="callingTable"
>
```

after doing some background work, I try to refresh the table using the reference but I get the error

**this.$refs.callingTable.refresh is not a function"**

```
<script>
  refreshTable(){
   ...
   this.$refs.callingTable.refresh();
  }
```

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Where is `refresh` defined?

Comment: I think you're looking for `.$forceUpdate()` rather than `refresh()`?

Comment: I'm not sure if there is a refresh functionality on v-data-table that can be accessed from ref, putting this aside are you calling refresh to update the data shown in the table? If so, updating the "getCallingDetails" Array should work just fine. By the way you can see callingTable ref either by console logging it or from vue dev tool to see if there is any refresh in it or not

Answer (score 0):

Force update is not good way to update your layout.
Just update your data and then the layout will be react.
If it's not, you can use key-chaining to acheive your problem.

[Key Chaining to force update](https://michaelnthiessen.com/force-re-render/)